# Can't get row values from the Kendo Grid unless they are in edit mode

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I can insert new rows and edit them, but I can't delete because, apparently, only when the row is selected and in edit mode, the values are passed to the codebehind.

The insert/edit/delete classes are in the codebehind in C#

This is the js code to perform the delete:

```
            var selectedRow;
            // deletes the selected row
            function doDelete() {
                var grid = $('#Grid').data('tGrid');
                if (selectedRow) {
                    grid.deleteRow($(selectedRow));
                }
                return false;
            }
```

And this is the code to perform the edit:

```
            function beginInsert() {
                var grid = $('#Grid').data('tGrid');

                // enter insert mode
                grid.addRow();

                // update the selected row
                selectedRow = $('#Grid .t-grid-new-row');

                // show the 'Insert' and 'Cancel' buttons and hide the 'Delete', 'Create' and 'Edit' buttons
                toggleInsertButtons(true);
                return false;
            }
            function endInsert() {
                var grid = $('#Grid').data('tGrid');
                // perform the insertion - call the _Insert action method
                grid.insertRow($(selectedRow));
                // hide the 'Insert' and 'Cancel' buttons and show the 'Delete', 'Create' and 'Edit' buttons
                toggleInsertButtons(false);
                return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a row you need to tell the grid widget what row it should remove, right? Your code is using `selectedRow` variable for that, which is populated in the (probably) edit event. That is why you can only delete when editing.

To remove the selected row anytime, just use [`select`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-select) and [`removeRow`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-removeRow) together:

```
function doDelete() {
    var grid = $('#Grid').data('kendoGrid');
    grid.deleteRow(grid.select());
}
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UPUNA)

Now, if you want to remove a row that is not selected, you have to someway select it and pass to the `removeRow` method:

```
function doDelete() {
    var grid = $('#Grid').data('kendoGrid');
    var row = $(grid.tbody).find("tr:first"); // Selects grid's first row

    grid.removeRow(row);
}
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UPUNA/3)

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful.

Comment: @zui glad to help!!